# How to combine engineering notation from siunitx with pgfplotstable

Tags: siunitx, pgfplotstable, engineering

I'm trying to get engineering notation (i.e. scientific notation in which the powers of ten must be multiples of three) in my tables produced by `pgfplotstable`.
Because `pgfplotstable` does not support this kind of notation, I'd like to use the `siunitx`-package to achieve this.
This is my example data-file called "testje.dat":

```
-0.974e-4 -7.46e-3
-0.948e-3 -7.45e-3
-0.923e-3 -7.43e-3
-0.845e-3 -7.4e-3
```

And this is my LaTeX-code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
   /pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code={%
    \def\pgfmathresult{#1}%
    \ifx\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfmathresult
    \else
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%
            \num{scientific-notation = engineering}{#1}%
        }%
    \fi
},
}
Now I'd like my table-values to be in engineering notation
\begin{table}[h!]
 \begin{center}
   \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=space,
    display columns/0/.style={column name=$U_O$, column type=|c|},
    display columns/1/.style={column name=$U_I$, column type=c|,verbatim},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
   ]{testje.dat}
 \end{center}
\caption{Auto generated table from space separated values file
\label{tab:data}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When trying to compile this by LaTeX I get the following errors:

```
siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"    
Invalid token 's' in numerical input.    
See the siunitx documentation for further information.
For immediate help type H <return>.    
l.30    ]{testje.dat}    
? H    
Numbers can only contain tokens defined using the 'input-...' options:    
the token 's' is not set up as a valid part of a number.
```

Could anyone here help me solving this issue?

thanks in advance
hugo

Answer (score 9):

Instead of rolling your own code for typesetting the numbers using the `\num` macro, you can just use the `S` column type that's provided by `siunitx` (note that you need to additionally use the `string type` keyword). That also allows you to use the `table-format` alignment options:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

   \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/0/.style={
        column name=$U_O$,
        string type,
        column type={S[scientific-notation = engineering, table-format=-3.1e-1]},
    },
    columns/1/.style={
        column name=$U_I$,
        string type,
        column type={S[scientific-notation = engineering, table-format=-1.2e-1]},
    },
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
   ]{
-0.974e-4 -7.46e-3
-0.948e-3 -7.45e-3
-0.923e-3 -7.43e-3
-0.845e-3 -7.4e-3
   }
\end{document}
```

---

As Joseph Wright noted in his comment, it might be a better idea to divide all the numbers in each column by a common factor to keep the table more readable. You can do this on the fly using the key `preproc/expr={##1 / 1e-6}`, for instance:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

   \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    multicolumn names,
    columns/0/.style={
        column name=$U_O / 10^{-6}$,
        string type,
        column type={S[scientific-notation = engineering, round-mode=figures, round-precision=3, table-format=-3.1]},
        preproc/expr={##1/1e-6}
    },
    columns/1/.style={
        column name=$U_I / 10^{-3}$,
        string type,
        column type={S[scientific-notation = engineering, round-mode=figures, round-precision=3, table-format=-1.2]},
        preproc/expr={##1/1e-3}
    },
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
   ]{
-0.974e-4 -7.46e-3
-0.948e-3 -7.45e-3
-0.923e-3 -7.43e-3
-0.845e-3 -7.4e-3
   }
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've divide the columns through here by an appropriate power of 10 :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Yup, good idea. I've edited my answer to show a way to do this on the fly. Thanks!

Comment: Can this idea also be combined with vertical lines surrounding the columns (kind of |c|c|)?